# scrbook margin - ratio between top and bottom is wrong

Tags: header-footer, margins, koma-script

I use the following document class

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}
```

with default header and footer (chapter/section in header and the page number in the footer)

My problem is, that the ratio between the margin of the header and the footer is not 1:2 when considering the header but **not** considering the footer. It is always 1:2 considering header  and footer. I already tested the commands *headinclude* and *footexclude*, but it did not solve the problem.

Does somebody have an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your "issue". Compare the following examples (the second one features the `headinclude` class option):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,headinclude]{scrbook}

\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Output (page 2) of both examples:

[image]